# Rename tag jquery-ias to infinite-ajax-scroll

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

The author of Infinite Ajax Scroll here. Can we rename the `jquery-ias` tag to `infinite-ajax-scroll`? Infinite Ajax Scroll is no longer dependent on jQuery and I also think `infinite-ajax-scroll` is better than the `ias` abbreviation. An alternative is to create a new `infinite-ajax-scroll` tag, but I rather not lose the history.

Btw, does a rename of a tag also redirect the old tag? So if we proceed, will https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ias redirect to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infinite-ajax-scroll?

Comment: Is it two versions: one that historically used jquery and a new one that doesn't?

Comment: Yes, correct. Versions before v3.0 are dependent on jquery, >= v3.0 not.

Comment: I think we better keep the old tag and only add a synonym.  New questions will only get the new tag, current questions with the tag keep it as is and can be found that way when needed. I would be very confused if I use a jquery depended lib to be forced to a tag for a lib that doesn't have jquery. Alternatively the current tagged questions need to get the jquery tag as well so no information / findability based  on tags is lost.

Comment: I'm fine with having a synonym, but I would prefer to have infinite-ajax-scroll as the leading tag. Did you mean it like that?

Comment: yeah, infinite-ajax-scroll would be the target.

Comment: My concern with using a tag named "infinite-ajax-scroll" for the specific package which you are wanting it to refer to is that name is *completely* descriptive of the functionality which is implemented by that package *and* it is a fairly common functionality, which has a substantial number of different implementations. There's nothing in the name "infinite-ajax-scroll" which would give users even a hint from just that text that the tag was intended to refer to a single package, rather than a type of functionality.

Comment: @Makyen I see your point. What would you suggest we do? Keeping it as `jquery-ias` is also fairly confusing, if it is no longer related to jquery.